# Application of Dynkin's Lemma: Uniqueness of measures associated with distribution function

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $\mu$ and $\nu$ two laws. We want to show that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ have the same distribution function $F$, then it must hold that $\mu=\nu$.

We want to use Dynkin's Lemma, so we have to show that they agree on a $\pi$-system generating $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Since the distribution function is the same, we have that $\mu((-\infty,a])=\nu((-\infty, a])$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now we claim that $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on the $\pi$-system $\mathcal{C}:=\{(a,b], a \leq b\}$.

I wonder: Is the set $\{ (-\infty, a], a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ not a $\pi$-system? Or not generating $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? Or why don't we work with that set?

Moreover, how can I show that $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $\mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{(-\infty, a] \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, so it could work just as well as $\mathcal{C} = \{(a, b] \mid a \leq b\}$. Using one over the other is a matter of preference.

Moreover, $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $\mathcal{C}$ since
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu((a, b])
&= \mu((-\infty, b]) - \mu((-\infty, a])
= F(b) - F(a) \\
&= \nu((-\infty, b]) - \nu((-\infty, a])
= \nu((a, b])
\end{aligned}
$$
for all $a \leq b$.